# Can't get data from weather API - JSON/Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a basic weather app using weatherapi.com to get the data. I have tried this and keep getting some weird errors, not sure if its my network or my code not working?

Weather

```
struct Weather: Codable {
    let current: Current
}

struct Current: Codable {
    let tempC: Int
    let tempF: Double
    let gustMph: Double
    let gustKph: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case tempC = "temp_c"
        case tempF = "temp_f"
        case gustMph = "gust_mph"
        case gustKph = "gust_kph"
    }
}
```

WeatherViewModel

```
class WeatherViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var tempC: String = "-"
    @Published var gustMph: String = "-"
    
    init() {
        fetchWeather()
    }
    
    func fetchWeather() {
                
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=APIKEY&q=London&aqi=no") else {
            return
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
            // get data
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            //convert data to model
            do {
                let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(Current.self, from: data)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tempC = "\(model.tempC)"
                    self.gustMph = "\(model.gustMph)"
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("failed")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = WeatherViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text(viewModel.tempC)
                    .font(.system(size: 50))
                Text(viewModel.gustMph)
                    .font(.system(size: 50))
            }   
            .navigationTitle("Weather Test")
        }
    }
}
```

I was trying to get the temp in celcuis and the wind gust in mph to display on the Content View but it is not working at all.

Comment: You are ignoring the response and the error that would tell you what is going on. I should say errors because you aren’t doing anything with the decoding error

Comment: `print("failed")` Is this called? Replace it anyways with ` print("Decoding failed: \(error)")`

Comment: @Larme It is not calling that line, not sure why

Comment: @loremipsum Tried printing errors and nothing is showing up rip

Comment: Put a print statement for the response and error above the guard

Comment: add `print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject)` just before the guard, and show us what it prints. Note you should probably try to decode `Weather.self` instead of `Current.self`. What does the docs say you should be getting from the server?

Comment: @JohnFromSwindon you are creating a wrong model and it doesn't give any response through the decoding method because you've to create exact model that the response is giving else the data couldn't come and it give errors.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Adding that line results in this error: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @NextDaySoftwareSolutionPvt I believe my model should be sufficient but even trying it with a model that contains all elements of the returning data it still doesn't work

Comment: @JohnFromSwindon if you don't have an urgent to extract the data in the model, so you can also use jsonSerialization method to extract the data properly. And getting this data through Jsondecoder while decoding the response in my model where tempC and gusMph have issue while decoding so I gave them optional so my decoding doesn't give error.

Comment: Weather(location: Optional(SampleSwiftUI.Location(name: Optional("London"), region: Optional("City of London, Greater London"), country: Optional("United Kingdom"), lat: Optional(51.52), lon: Optional(-0.11), tzID: nil, localtimeEpoch: nil, localtime: Optional("2023-07-06 14:20")))


half on next comment.

Comment: , current: Optional(SampleSwiftUI.Current(condition: Optional(SampleSwiftUI.Condition(text: Optional("Sunny"), icon: Optional("//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png"), code: Optional(1000))), windMph: nil, windKph: nil, windDir: nil, tempF: nil, lastUpdated: nil, gustMph: nil, feelslikeF: nil, uv: Optional(6), humidity: Optional(46), cloud: Optional(0), precipMm: nil, visKM: nil, visMiles: nil, precipIn: nil, windDegree: nil, tempC: nil, pressureMB: nil, pressureIn: nil, lastUpdatedEpoch: nil, isDay: nil, feelslikeC: nil, gustKph: nil)))

Comment: Are you by chance, not injecting your API key into the url when you send your request? `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=` your API Key is supposed to go here `&q=London&aqi=no`.

Comment: @Yrb Yes I did inject it

Answer (score 1):

I went back and looked at this. First, I am going to give you an [invaluable extension](https://gist.github.com/cprovatas/5c9f51813bc784ef1d7fcbfb89de74fe) for working with JSON data with all credit going to Charlton Provatas, slightly modified:

```
extension Data {
    var prettyPrintedJSONString: NSString { /// NSString gives us a nice sanitized debugDescription
        guard let object = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self, options: []),
              let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object, options: [.prettyPrinted]),
              let prettyPrintedString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) else { return "nil" }
        
        return prettyPrintedString
    }
}
```

This will allow you to write:

```
print(jsonData.prettyPrintedJSONString)
```

and have a nice printout of the data you downloaded, before attempting to decode it.

First critique: Any model you make to decode JSON data should be all optional unless you control the server. Even if you do control the server, make it all optional, otherwise a serve change breaks you decoder. Therefore, your model becomes this:

```
struct Weather: Codable {
    let current: Current?
}

struct Current: Codable {
    let tempC: Double?
    let tempF: Double?
    let gustMph: Double?
    let gustKph: Double?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case tempC = "temp_c"
        case tempF = "temp_f"
        case gustMph = "gust_mph"
        case gustKph = "gust_kph"
    }
}
```

Second critique: Read you API documentation carefully. `tempC` and `gustKph` are `Doubles`, not `Ints`.

That still wasn't enough. Remember what you are downloading from WeatherAPI.com: `Weather`. You can't directly decode a `Current` from a `Weather`. Your decoder will fail every time because you are asking it to decode a `Weather` as if it was a `Current`. Therefore, change your decoder to:

```
let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(Weather.self, from: data)
```